# Convert html to image

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, image, render

Is there a way to use the firefox (or chrome or any other good browsers) rendering engine to convert html (as a text string) to an image?

I have full access to the server I'm using, so no limitations there.

Comment: Any background to what you're trying to achieve? Do you mean take a screenshot of the site, or somehow interpret the HTML itself as image data?

Comment: are you asking for c# code to do that (screen shot an HTML page as an image)? the question is vague

Comment: The two answers below is exactly what I wanted, evaluating them now. I also found IECapt and CutyCapt, but none of them seem to support rounded corners (css) - to bad.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Awesomium](http://www.khrona.com/products/awesomium/) and its managed wrapper [WPF Chromium](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/wpf-chromium-webbrowser-source-code/) which contains a [small utility](http://wpfchromium.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/28084#458135) allowing you to achieve this very easily.

Comment: While this seems like a great solution, unfortunately this solution costs to much :(